# optimal collection of elements from the object and carrying out operations on them

Tags: c#

I have object with elements which looks like that:

```
class Card
{
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressIndex { get; set; }
    public int Entry1 { get; set; }
    public int Entry2 { get; set; }
    public int Entry3 { get; set; }
    public int Entry4 { get; set; }
    public int Entry5 { get; set; }
    public int Entry6 { get; set; }
    public int Entry7 { get; set; }
    public int Entry8 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter1 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter2 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter3 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter4 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter5 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter6 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter7 { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter8 { get; set; }
}
```

I had to connect with each other elements `Entry1` and `AdditionalParameter1` and so on.
How can I do it optimally?

The only thing that comes to my mind is create table, and add every value, because i cant do `object[i] + object[i+8]`.

Is there a more optimal solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect with each other"? I think you should use a list/array to store the entries and additional parameters. And if they are related, use a dictionary.

Comment: I want do loop for 8 times, and hand down in sequence  values from Entry1 and AdditionalParameter1.In the next Entry2 and AdditionalParameter2 . And so 8 times.

Comment: Receives Card as the entire object and i am looking for better solution than rewrite all values to array or dictionary. Is there other solution?

Comment: That's much more clearer. Thank you. Does each entry + additional parameter pair represent something? If they do, you can wrap them in a struct.

Comment: Naver use struct. But i think it would also bind with rewrite object. I meant something more like a quick projection on a blackboard, without having to rewrite each element. Or referring to the index somehow. However, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store two arrays instead:

```
class Card
{
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressIndex { get; set; }
    public int[] Entries { get; set; } = new int[8];
    public int[] AdditionalParameters { get; set; } = new int[8];
}
```

You would refer to `Entry1` as `Entries[0]`, `Entry2` as `Entries[1]`, and so on. Same goes for the `AdditionalParameters`. Now you can loop over them very easily.

If you can think of a better name than `EntryParameterPair`, you can go one step further and wrap the two values in a struct:

```
struct EntryParameterPair {
    public int Entry { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameter { get; set; }
}
```

And then create a single array of `EntryParameterPair`s:

```
class Card
{
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressIndex { get; set; }
    public EntryParameterPair[] EntryParameterPairs { get; set; } = new EntryParameterPair[8];
}
```

You would refer to `Entry1` as `EntryParameterPairs[0].Entry`, `AdditionalParameter1` as `EntryParameterPairs[0].AdditionalParameter`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when you find yourself creating properties like `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3` and so on, the answer is to use some kind of collection, often that's a `List` in C#.

In your case you want to group two values together. There are multiple ways for you to do that. A simple approach would be to use a wrapper struct (or class) that holds the values and put those in a list:

```
class Card
{
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressIndex { get; set; }

    public List<CardValues> Values { get; set; } // I don't know a good name for this
}

class CardValues
{
    public int Entry { get; set; }
    public int AdditionalParameters { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can adress them like this: `var values = card.CardValues[5];`. Note that this will throw an exception if there are less than six items in your list.

To add new values into this list, you can either just call `card.CardValues.Add(new CardValues { Entry = 1, AdditionalParameters = 5 });`, which will insert these values at the end of the list or call [`List.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.8) to put them in a specific place.